# PTR records for mail server

Tags: postfix, ptr-record

If the domain for our outbound emails is mail.example.com and the MX records (mail servers) for this domain are:

mail1.example.com and mail2.example.com what's the prpoer PTR records in this case:

```
192.168.1.1 - mail.example.com
192.168.1.2 - mail.example.com
```

OR

```
192.168.1.1 - mail1.example.com
192.168.1.2 - mail2.example.com
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really have anything to do with your mx records, outgoing mail and incoming mail can be routed through separate servers.

PTR should always match the hostname of the server. So if you have two outbound servers *mail1.example.com* and *mail2.example.com* then correct PTRs would be

```
mail1.example.com for the IP of mail1.example.com
mail2.example.com for the IP of mail2.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be like :
IN      PTR     mail1.domain.com.  ( on first domain zone )
IN      PTR     mail2.domain.com. ( on secound domain zone )

Comment: "Domain zone" ?